# I am getting a different ISO date strings when using nestjs with `class-transformer` with difference in milliseconds

Tags: node.js, date, nestjs, class-transformer

I am writing a test for a nestjs application, however, the output dates and the expected dates do not match:

This is the mock generator:

```
export function createMockUser(data: Partial<User>): User {
  return {
    id: data.id || randomUUID(),
    firstName: data.firstName || faker.name.firstName(),
    lastName: data.lastName || faker.name.lastName(),
    emailAddress: data.emailAddress || faker.internet.email(),
    createdAt: data.createdAt || new Date(),
    updatedAt: data.updatedAt || new Date(),
  };
}
```

This is the test:

```
  describe('create', () => {
    it('creates and returns user', async () => {
      const randomUser = createMockUser({});

      const user = new UserEntity(randomUser);
      usersServiceCreateMock.mockResolvedValue(user);

      const response = await tester.http
        .post('/api/users')
        .set('Accept', 'application/json')
        .set('Authorization', 'Bearer fake-token')
        .send({
          firstName: randomUser.firstName,
          lastName: randomUser.lastName,
        })
        .expect(201);

        expect(response.body).toEqual(instanceToPlain(user));
     });
  });
```

If anyone is interested this is the controller:

```
@UseGuards(FirebaseAuthGuard)
@ApiBearerAuth()
@UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)
@Controller('users')
export class UsersController {
  constructor(private readonly usersService: UsersService) {}

  @Post()
  async create(
    @Body() createUserDto: CreateUserPostDto,
    @CurUser() user: DecodedIdToken
  ): Promise<UserEntity> {
    return await this.usersService.create({
      ...createUserDto,
      id: user.uid,
      emailAddress: user.email,
    });
  }
}
```

This is the output:

This is the output:

```
    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    - Expected  - 3
    + Received  + 3

    - UserEntity {
    -   "createdAt": 2022-08-21T13:25:49.621Z,
    + Object {
    +   "createdAt": "2022-08-21T13:25:49.771Z",
        "emailAddress": "Tyshawn.Hudson@gmail.com",
        "firstName": "Billy",
        "id": "ead38580-287f-4003-8f8c-e1c5e2243cfd",
        "lastName": "Bins",
    -   "updatedAt": 2022-08-21T13:25:49.621Z,
    +   "updatedAt": "2022-08-21T13:25:49.772Z",
      }
```

I don't know what's causing the difference in milliseconds.

The outcome is the same even when I am not using `instanceToPlain(user)`, the outcome is also the same if I apply a Transform on the dates, e.g.:

```
  @Transform(({ value }) => value.toISOString())
  createdAt: Date;
  @Transform(({ value }) => value.toISOString())
  updatedAt: Date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please notice that you create a mock user with `new Date()` for both `createdAt` and `updatedAt` fields and then you use this user object to create a document in the DB. However, as I suppose, `createdAt` and `updatedAt` timestamps are not specified in your schema and are populated automatically using absolutely new timestamps. That's why you experience these discrepancies.

Comment: Nothing is being saved to the database, I am using a spy which returns the same mocked object.